# using with-open to initialize unknown number of readers/writers in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Say that I have a file to be used by n readers and m writers. When I know n and m's value, say if n==3 and m==1, I could write a code like this:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(with-open [rdr1 (Reader file)
            rdr2 (Reader file)
            rdr3 (Reader file)
            wtr1 (Writer file)]
    (time-to-work-out-guys))
```

Now the case is, the app user determines values of n and m, so I have no idea what value n and m would have. Is there any way that I still can use with-open to initialize readers/writers and do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `open-with` is a macro instead of a function, the only way to build this would be with a macro that generates a call to open-with and then use eval to compile this at runtime. So while technically the **answer is yes, I can't honestly recommend doing so**. open-with is a convenience that does not fit all cases.

In this case it makes more sense to write your own `(try .... (finally ...))` statement.